# 2D Arrays Minesweeper Surrounding Mines

Tags: java, arrays, cell

Still stuck on a previous question I asked, but I thought I'd make a new post to clean things up a little (sorry if this is bothersome).

I'm struggling with showing the 'surrounding mines' of a/the cells. What I need to do is allow the user to clear a cell, and, if mines are nearby, show how many are there, such as:
How am I able to display the mines that surrounds a cell within my array output of say:

Replacing:

```
 0  1  2  3  4
0| .  .  .  .  . 
1| .  .  .  .  . 
2| .  .  .  .  * 
3| .  .  *  .  . 
4| *  .  .  *  *
```

With:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0| .  .  .  .  . 
1| .  .  .  1  1 
2| .  .  1  2  * 
3| 1  2  *  2  2 
4| *  1  2  *  *
```

The code that I am using to place mines is:

```
    public MineField(int w, int h, int m)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        mineField = new State[w][h];
        surroundingMines = new int[w][h];
        initialiseMineField = new int[w][h];
        traceOn = true; //set to false before submitting
        width = w;
        height = h;
        mineCount = m;
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            {
                mineField[i][j] = State.COVERED;
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int a = r.nextInt(w);
                int b = r.nextInt(h);
                if (mineField[a][b] != State.MINED)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            mineField[r.nextInt(w)][r.nextInt(h)] = State.MINED;
        }
    }
```

And I display my 'minefield' via:

```
public void displayField(boolean showTruth)
    {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
        {
            System.out.print("  " + col);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
        {
            System.out.print("" + row + "|");
            for (int col = 0; col < width; col++)
            {
                //TODO: You need to complete this method by printing the correct character for the current field cell
                if (mineField[row][col] == State.MINED)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + '*' + " " );
                }
                if (mineField[row][col] == State.EXPLODED)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + '+' + " " );
                }
                if (mineField[row][col] == State.COVERED)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + '.' + " " );
                }
                if (mineField[row][col] == State.CLEARED)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + ' ' + " " );
                }
                if (mineField[row][col] == State.FLAGGED)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + 'F' + " " );
                }
                if (mineField[row][col] == State.MISFLAGGED)
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + 'F' + " " );
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

I'd appreciate any help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a method that counts the cells that have the `State.MINED`, given the coordinates of a particular cell. As mentioned in a comment, this can be done with two `for` loops, iterating over the neighborhood of one cell. A helper method that returns whether some given neighbor coordinates are "valid" may come in handy here. So it could roughly look like this:

```
private int countMines(int x, int y) 
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (int dx=-1; dx<=1; dx++)
    {
        for (int dy=-1; dy<=1; dy++)
        {
            if (dx == 0 && dy == 0) 
            {
                continue; 
            }
            int nx = x+dx;
            int ny = y+dy;
            if (!isValid(nx, ny))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (mineField[nx][ny] == State.MINED)
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

private boolean isValid(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || x >= mineField.length) return false;
    if (y < 0 || y >= mineField[x].length) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Tnx, man. Your solution was great. I have the same problem and you don't know how much I searched and find nothing. but this solution and analyzes were brilliant. tnx so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post what you have tried writing to count the mines before we can comment on the code for it...

However I did see this:

```
        while (true)
        {
            int a = r.nextInt(w);
            int b = r.nextInt(h);
            if (mineField[a][b] != State.MINED)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Which is bad. If you ever use `while (true)` you almost certainly have something wrong.

```
        int a, b;
        do {
            a = r.nextInt(w);
            b = r.nextInt(h);
        } while (mineField[a][b] != State.MINED);
```

Comment: I'd love to show you my attempts, but that's the thing, I haven't the faintest clue on how to actually approach this... I assume I require for loops within an if to go through the array of rows and columns, and check if they're mined. But then what?

Comment: Initialize a counter to 0. Loop from x-1 to x+1 and y-1 to y+1 incrementing the counter for each mine you see. That's your count of mines. Be aware of the edges of the board.